# When SAP call WSO2 listener with bapi, it doesn't wait the answer

Tags: wso2, abap, wso2-esb

SAP calls WSO2 listener with:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'ZBC_IEBCXX_FONCTION_TEST'
  DESTINATION p_dest
  ...
```

(P_DEST is an TCP/IP RFC destination with registered server program)

The call is ok and the WSO2 flow works.

But SAP doesn't wait the answer, what must be done to have the call wait the answer (in SAP or in WSO2 flow).

I have tried different DataMapper.

But it seems SAP really doesn't wait, tested with the code below (SAP closes the call function before the sleep 4s is finished)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="DE1_Listener_To_IE1_100_BAPI" startOnLoad="true" statistics="enable"
        trace="enable" transports="bapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <script language="js"><![CDATA[java.lang.Thread.sleep(4000);]]></script>
        <log level="full"/>
.....
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log description="L3" level="full"/>
        <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/Call_Back_ZBC_IEBCXX_FONCTION_TEST.dmc"
          inputSchema="gov:datamapper/Call_Back_ZBC_IEBCXX_FONCTION_TEST_inputSchema.json"
          inputType="XML"
          outputSchema="gov:datamapper/Call_Back_ZBC_IEBCXX_FONCTION_TEST_outputSchema.json"
          outputType="XML"
          xsltStyleSheet="gov:datamapper/Call_Back_ZBC_IEBCXX_FONCTION_TEST_xsltStyleSheet.xml"/>
        <log/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
<parameter name="transport.sap.serverName">FRIDADEVSAP01</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.sap.enableErrorListener">enabled</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.sap.enableTIDHandler">enabled</parameter>
</proxy>
```

How to have a complete CALL function to WSO2 (from SAP) asking/receiving the answer?

Comment: Either WSO2 launches a part of itself asynchronously, or the ABAP program launches `ZBC_IEBCXX_FONCTION_TEST` asynchronously. For the ABAP part, `CALL FUNCTION` runs asynchronously only if there are additional words like `STARTING NEW TASK`or `IN BACKGROUND...`; I am not sure if you have truncated that part or not in your post.

Comment: Sandra : thanks for your answer
I have no asynchronous command in my ABAP CALL RFC
just 
CALL FUNCTION 'ZBC'
  DESTINATION p_dest